# Converting an application from Unity3d to Flash

Tags: json, flash, unity-game-engine, code-conversion

I am attempting to convert my Unity3d game to flash but am experiencing trouble with comments. Because of the socket trouble, I am trying to use Json and Post, but I don't know where to start. I saw this 
[Java server- client socket communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665331/java-server-client-socket-communication)

but it incorporates sockets.

This is for the user client, but I also need to redo the server side. I believe I need a web server to get the Json strings and return the appropriate response.

Am I doing this right, or is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

This may lessen the amount of work quite a bit if you are interested in using an API.  Smartfox is an awesome Client API / Multiplayer server tool that can increase output time as well as allow you to implement efficiency code to improve server stability.

It works for both Unity3D and flash.
http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

Addressing your main question I believe you would need a server to effectively use Json and be able to communicate to the clients however this is where smartfoxserver can come in handy.  I have not had much experience in the flash multiplayer programming however smartfox is a great tool and I used it to make multiplayer programs in unity3d.

Hope this helps!
Mitch